# How to get current user profile pic via VK API (Open API)?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, vk

I launched an Iframed application in VK and now I am trying to get user Info and user profile pic as well.
I was looking into their documentation but it seemed very messy.
Can anyone help me? 
It will be more preferable to get the data with JavaScript.